# Randomly select an element from a list

Tags: probability, algorithms, random-variables

Suppose I have a list that contains *N* elements, every time I randomly select an element from it and mark it as visited. What is the expected number of selection that I have to make until all the elements in the list are marked as visited?

Comment: This is the "coupon-collector's" problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With $N$ elements, the expected number of selections you have to make is

$$N \displaystyle\sum_{k=1}^N \frac{1}{k}$$

As was noted in the comments, this is called the [coupon collector's problem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Coupon_collector%27s_problem#Calculating_the_expectation).